# fazer desaparecer um botão

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, mvc, jquery-datatables

Tenho um código aonde ele cria um tabela caso tenha um registro no banco de dados. Nessa tabela, na última coluna tem um botão que ao clicar abre uma tela mais detalhada sobre aquela linha da tabela. Preciso fazer com que esse botão apareça apenas nas primeiras duas linhas da tabela, fazendo com que nas outras não apareça nenhum botão. Estou tentando de várias maneiras, mas até agora não consegui nenhum avanço. Meu código está em CodeIgniter.

View:

```
<div data-widget-editbutton="false" id="wid-id-0" class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-blueDark jarviswidget-sortable" role="widget">
    <header role="heading">
        <h2><?= $this->lang->line("view_laudo_wg_title"); ?></h2>
    </header>


    <div role="content">
        <div class="jarviswidget-editbox">
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body no-padding">
            <div class="widget-body-toolbar">
            </div>
            <?= $this->table->generate(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    pageSetUp();
    var iMin;
    var iMax;

    $("#filtrar_data").on('click', function () {
        iMin = $('#dateMin').val();
        iMax = $('#dateMax').val();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });

    var oTable = $('#tabletools').dataTable({
        "sProcessing": '<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_process"); ?>',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url() . $caminho; ?>",
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
            $("td:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(4)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(4)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(5)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(5)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(6)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(6)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(7)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(7)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
        },
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_process"); ?>",
            "sZeroRecords": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_records"); ?>",
            "sInfo": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_info"); ?>",
            "sInfoEmpty": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_empty"); ?>",
            "sInfoFiltered": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_filter"); ?>",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sUrl": "",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_first"); ?>",
                "sPrevious": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_previous"); ?>",
                "sNext": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_next"); ?>",
                "sLast": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_last"); ?>"
            }
        },
        "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
            $(this).closest('#dt_table_tools_wrapper').find('.DTTT.btn-group').addClass('table_tools_group').children('a.btn').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('btn-sm btn-default');
            });
            $("td:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(4)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(4)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(5)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(5)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(6)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(6)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(7)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(7)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
        },
        'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({name: '<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>', value: '<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>'});
            aoData.push({name: "sSearch_1", value: iMin});
            aoData.push({name: "sSearch_2", value: iMax});
            $.ajax
                    ({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'url': sSource,
                        'data': aoData,
                        'success': fnCallback
                    });

        }
    });

</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function index() {
        $tmpl = array('table_open' => '<table id="tabletools" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-hover dataTable" aria-describedby="datatable_tabletools_info">');
        $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
        $this->table->set_heading('' . $this->lang->line("con_laudo_th_ti") . '', '' . $this->lang->line("con_laudo_th_dh") . '', '' . $this->lang->line("con_laudo_th_op") . '', '' . $this->lang->line("con_laudo_th_di") . '', '' . $this->lang->line("con_laudo_th_de") . '', '' . $this->lang->line("con_laudo_th_nr") . '', '' . $this->lang->line("con_laudo_th_pe") . '', '' . $this->lang->line("con_laudo_th_ac") . '');
        $data['caminho'] = 'ConLaudos/generateTable';

            $this->load->view('ViewLaudos', $data);

    }

    public function generateTable() {

            echo $this->ML->getLaudos($this->lang->line("con_laudo_tip_insp_v"), $this->lang->line("con_laudo_tip_insp_e"), $this->lang->line("con_laudo_per_insp_u"), $this->lang->line("con_laudo_per_insp_r"), $this->lang->line("con_laudo_acoes_insp"));

    }
```

Model:

```
public function getLaudos($vei, $est, $urb, $rur, $aca) {
        $this->datatables->select('ls.lau_id, ls.lau_tipo, ls.lau_data, usu.usr_nome, dispo.dsp_nome, ls.lau_densidade, ls.lau_nivel, ls.lau_zona, ls.lau_status');
        $this->datatables->from('ls');
        $this->datatables->join('usu', 'ls.usr_id = usu.usr_id');
        $this->datatables->join('dispo', 'ls.dsp_id = dispo.dsp_id');
        $this->datatables->join('empresa', 'empresa.emp_id = usu.emp_id');
        $this->datatables->where('usu.emp_id = ' . $this->session->userdata('emp_id') . ' AND usu.usr_nivel<>0');

        $this->datatables->unset_column('ls.lau_id');
        $this->datatables->unset_column('ls.lau_status');
        $this->datatables->add_column('Ações', '$1', 'get_buttons_ls(ls.lau_id, ls.lau_status, ls.lau_tipo,' . $aca . ')');
        $this->datatables->edit_column('ls.lau_tipo', '$1', 'trataLauTipo(ls.lau_tipo,' . $vei . ',' . $est . ')');
        $this->datatables->edit_column('ls.lau_data', '$1', 'tratarDataHora(ls.lau_data)');
        $this->datatables->edit_column('ls.lau_zona', '$1', 'trataLauPerimetro(ls.lau_zona,' . $urb . ',' . $rur . ')');
        $this->datatables->edit_column('ls.lau_status', '$1', 'trataLauStatus(ls.lau_status)');
        return $this->datatables->generate();
    }
```

Comment: Porque tantas repetições no nth-child? Além disso vocé pode fazer isso dessa forma:  childrens[number] = 'nth-child('+number+')'; $('td:'+childrens+',th:'+childrens).addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs')

Comment: @IvanFerrer esse código foi outra pessoa que fez, eu apenas estou arrumando ele, não sei exatamente o motivo de tanta repetições. Eu já tentei entrar em contato com o mesmo, mas não me responde. Desde já gradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Altere seu código para isso:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function setClassTable() {
     $("td:nth-child(1),th:nth-child(1)")
            .addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');

      for (var i=4; i<=7; i++) {
             $("td:nth-child("+i+"),th:nth-child("+i+")")
             .addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
      }
         $("tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-last-child(1),tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-last-child(1)")
            .removeClass('hidden-md')
            .removeClass('hidden-sm')
            .removeClass('hidden-xs');
  }
    pageSetUp();
    var iMin;
    var iMax;

    $("#filtrar_data").on('click', function () {
        iMin = $('#dateMin').val();
        iMax = $('#dateMax').val();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });

    var oTable = $('#tabletools').dataTable({
        "sProcessing": '<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_process"); ?>',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url() . $caminho; ?>",
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {

         setClassTable();

         $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
        },
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_process"); ?>",
            "sZeroRecords": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_records"); ?>",
            "sInfo": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_info"); ?>",
            "sInfoEmpty": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_empty"); ?>",
            "sInfoFiltered": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_filter"); ?>",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sUrl": "",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_first"); ?>",
                "sPrevious": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_previous"); ?>",
                "sNext": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_next"); ?>",
                "sLast": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_last"); ?>"
            }
        },
        "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
            $(this).closest('#dt_table_tools_wrapper').find('.DTTT.btn-group').addClass('table_tools_group').children('a.btn').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('btn-sm btn-default');
            });

         setClassTable();
        },
        'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({name: '<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>', value: '<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>'});
            aoData.push({name: "sSearch_1", value: iMin});
            aoData.push({name: "sSearch_2", value: iMax});
            $.ajax
                    ({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'url': sSource,
                        'data': aoData,
                        'success': fnCallback
                    });

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: coloquei esse código que você enviou, não mudou nada, aparece o botão em todos registros ainda, e não apenas nos dois primeiro. Obrigada!

Comment: @Ketlin, publica o método $this->table->generate(), esse que constrói a tabela, eu preciso ver como você está montando isso, ou construa a tabela para eu entender onde você quer esconder os 2 primeiros botões. Quantas colunas e linhas têm?

Comment: eu coloquei todo o código que eu tenho, não fui eu que fiz, eu tenho que arrumar ele apenas. Também não estou entendendo ele direito. Tudo que eu tenho relacionado a essa tabela é isso. Ela tem 8 colunas, sendo que na ultima vai esse botão. No controller no generateTable na parte $this->lang->line("con_laudo_acoes_insp")); é aonde está o nome do botão. Espero que tenho ajudado. Grata pela atenção

Comment: Eu fiz uma alteração, veja se funciona agora.

Comment: Também não funcionou, a tela fica com a mensagem que está carregando os dados e o botão também não desapareceu.

Comment: Eu pensei em fazer uma equação(todos os registros - todos os registros + 2 registros) entretanto não obtive sucesso em transformar em código.

Comment: Essa última coluna, como é a estrutura dela? Você pode ocultar o botão dentro do for. tipo: if (i > 2) { 'esconde elemento'; } e deixa os outros visíveis, no caso, vc pode também pode passar a clase eu acho que é algo como table:last-of-type

Comment: Agora acho que está certo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26152/discussion-between-ivan-ferrer-and-ketlin).

Comment: abri a discussão no chat. Grata